# MultiLabelBinarizer not working for a column with multiple arrays

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a column with 15000 arrays. please find sample of 2 such records out of 15000. I want to create dummies for the values in under Genres_relevant.

```
user Genres_relevant    
 1         [2.0]
 2     [3.0,2.0,1.0]
```

Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
df=pd.DataFrame(users_list['Genres_relevant'])
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
```

Expected output

```
   1.0  2.0  3.0
1   0    1    0
2   1    1    1
```

Error:
The shape of passed values is (12, 1), indices imply (12, 15000)

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['Genres_relevant']), columns=mlb.classes_, 
         index=df.index)
```

When you are fitting do not pass in the full dataframe but rather pass in the column.